# I want to get html of a mail by imap protocol in php

Tags: php, gmail-imap

I want to get html body of an email using IMAP protocol in PHP.

I use `imap_fetchbody()` function of IMAP  module but I am not getting html body of an email.
 Is it possible ?

If possible then which function or code is used for it?

Answer (score 0):

if you have control over you're server, install and use the PEAR packages.
They are excellent in opening and editing mail formats such as IMAP and mbox

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the body of the mail in html,

```
$html_message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, "1.2"); 
         // NOTE: "1.2" here is a string and not an integer.
```

Details:

```
()Root Message Part (multipart/related)
(1) The text parts of the message (multipart/alternative)
(1.1) Plain text version (text/plain)
(1.2) HTML version (text/html)
(2) The background stationary (image/gif)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php